# Required changing in controls like labels at runtime in C #

Tags: c#

[image: These are 10 labels on form1 by named label1,label2,....,label10]

I want to change labels controls text like if label name is label1 so 1 is odd, the text of label1 should be changed into 1 and if label named is label2 then label text should be changed into 2 and so on.

The following code is not working.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       for(int ai =1; ai<=13; ai++)
        {
            if(ai % 2 == 0)
            {
                Controls["label" + ai.ToString()].Text = ai.ToString ();
            }

            else
            {
               Controls["label" + ai.ToString()].Text = ai.ToString ();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the assignment seems to be identical: `Controls["label" + ai.ToString()].Text = ai.ToString ();` why is it not working? what error do you get?

Comment: Sir Martin Liversage                                                                                        Error An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Comment: seems like your `Controls["label" + ai.ToString()]` is not found

Comment: sir control is available on the form1 but code not working when i code label1.text = "1" then it works but with name concatenation it not works

Comment: Sir Martin Liversage.....thanks a lot, problem is solved by your statements...

Comment: You got it wrong. I am Ian, not Martin Liversage. Martin Liversage is the one who edits your question (therefore his profile picture appears in your question) but I am the one who talks with you (therefore you see the name "Ian" in the last part of the comment, something like this "- **Ian** 20 hours ago"). Martin Liversage never talks to you.

Comment: Sir Ian ..thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `this.Controls.Find()`

refer [Control.ControlCollection.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.80).aspx)

you can try like

```
Control ctrl = this.Controls.Find("label" + ai.ToString(), false)[0];
ctrl.Text = ai.ToString();
```

or

```
this.Controls.Find("label" + ai.ToString(), false)[0].Text = ai.ToString();
```

Comment: Sir Sanjay Nishad Thanks  i try to do.

Comment: sir there is an error, IndexOutofRangeException was unhandled

Comment: @BiLaLJaMiL your lable name `lable1`, `lable2`,... are wrong, please check your control name

Comment: Sir,  all control name are correct...i have checked carefully

Comment: you have added `ai<=13;` to your `for` loop, is the number `13` is correct?

Comment: @BiLaLJaMiL Good! Can you please accept answer and vote up? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you put your labels in a panel you could do it like this :

```
 foreach (var control in myPanel.Controls)
            {
                if (control is Label)
                {
                    Label myLabel=control as Label;
                    myLabel.Text = myLabel.Name.Substring("label".Length);
                }
            }
```